# Braintree errors with GAE - Connection Errors - 5 Attempt to get blocked socket option

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, braintree

```
INFO     2015-10-09 11:07:31,718 connectionpool.py:695] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com
DEBUG    2015-10-09 11:07:31,724 api_server.py:277] Handled remote_socket.Resolve in 0.0028
DEBUG    2015-10-09 11:07:31,728 api_server.py:277] Handled remote_socket.CreateSocket in 0.0009
DEBUG    2015-10-09 11:07:32,049 api_server.py:277] Handled remote_socket.Connect in 0.3168
DEBUG    2015-10-09 11:07:32,055 api_server.py:272] Exception while handling service_name: "remote_socket"
method: "GetSocketOptions"
request: "\n$d15a35d7-d299-43c1-ba76-8bf4107f8850\022\006\010\001\020\003\032\000"
request_id: "aiUMNcTaLS"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abc/Downloads/google-appengine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 247, in _handle_POST
    api_response = _execute_request(request).Encode()
  File "/home/abc/Downloads/google-appengine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 186, in _execute_request
    make_request()
  File "/home/abc/Downloads/google-appengine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 181, in make_request
    request_id)
  File "/home/abc/Downloads/google-appengine/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub.py", line 131, in MakeSyncCall
    method(request, response)
  File "/home/abc/Downloads/google-appengine/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket_stub.py", line 56, in WrappedMethod
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abc/Downloads/google-appengine/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket_stub.py", line 265, in _Dynamic_GetSocketOptions
    'Attempt to get blocked socket option.')
ApplicationError: ApplicationError: 5 Attempt to get blocked socket option.


DEBUG    2015-10-09 11:07:32,056 api_server.py:277] Handled remote_socket.GetSocketOptions in 0.0014
INFO     2015-10-09 11:07:32,058 views.py:570] handle_exception
INFO     2015-10-09 21:28:17,317 views.py:559] Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/abc/Downloads/google-appengine/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/abc/projects/src/views.py", line 806, in get
    self._callHandlingMethod(url, self.getRegexps)

  File "/home/abc/projects/src/views.py", line 883, in _callHandlingMethod
    function(*matched.groups())

  File "/home/abc/projects/src/views.py", line 2992, in buy_get
    "client_token": braintree.ClientToken.generate(),

  File "/home/abc/projects/src/lib/braintree/client_token.py", line 25, in generate
    return gateway.generate(params)

  File "/home/abc/projects/src/lib/braintree/client_token_gateway.py", line 17, in generate
    response = self.config.http().post("/client_token", params)

  File "/home/abc/projects/src/lib/braintree/util/http.py", line 49, in post
    return self.__http_do("POST", path, params)

  File "/home/abc/projects/src/lib/braintree/util/http.py", line 66, in __http_do
    status, response_body = http_strategy.http_do(http_verb, full_path, self.__headers(), request_body)

  File "/home/abc/projects/src/lib/braintree/util/http.py", line 87, in http_do
    timeout=self.config.timeout

  File "/home/abc/projects/src/lib/requests/api.py", line 92, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)

  File "/home/abc/projects/src/lib/requests/api.py", line 48, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

  File "/home/abc/projects/src/lib/requests/sessions.py", line 451, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "/home/abc/projects/src/lib/requests/sessions.py", line 557, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "/home/abc/projects/src/lib/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

This seemed to be a https issue. I have tried different approaches

a) https://github.com/agfor/braintree-python-appengine . Gave me same error

b) I thought this could be the error from this issue - https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#openssl-pyopenssl 
But on updating required libraries , I get stuck at OpenSSL.crypto failed import.

Help anyone!

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. You shouldn't be using `pyopenssl` so that shouldn't be the problem. Try replacing that `raise e` with just `raise` so you at least see the full error backtrace, then update your question and reply to me here.

Comment: @agf Changed the Traceback. Now check please

Comment: This seems like a problem with your local permissions. If you run as a super user, do you still get the problem? Also, what happens if you switch your value of `GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB` (see the README in the braintre-python-appengine repo for more info)?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @agf Yeah, I had to hack the braintree library . Ill provide the result as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Braintree Version - `3.20.0`
Requests version - `2.7.0`

With the help of my friend , I used the following hack -
in `braintree/util/http.py` in the method - `__http_do`

```
    from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
    .....
    .....
    try:
        if http_verb in ["POST", "PUT"]:
            result = urlfetch.fetch(url=full_path,
                    payload=request_body,
                    method=urlfetch.POST,
                    headers=self.__headers())
            logging.debug('result: %r' % result)
            status = result.status_code
            response_body = result.content
            logging.debug(result.content)
        else:
            status, response_body = http_strategy.http_do(http_verb, full_path, self.__headers(), request_body)
    except Exception as e:
       .....
       .....
```

Using this hack, I was able to get things working. Hope this helps anybody coming across the same issue.

Comment: This really isn't the right way to solve the problem. If you wanted to use the urlfetch api directly, you should write an http strategy (basically an object with an http_do method) and set it in the configuration. But the Braintree library definitely works unmodified on GAE with the right version of requests (see the example you linked in your question) so you really shouldn't be doing this at all.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like braintree is trying to use a socket option unsupported by GAE, you can see a list of supported options here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/ which also states that attempting to get an unsupported option will raise an error

Comment: Braintree isn't setting any socket options directly, though it's possible `requests` or `urllib3` are. As this worked until recently, I doubt that's the problem.